# Cell color change after click on butonfiled

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am working with `gridview` in asp.net, inside `gridview` buttonfields applied when I click on buttonfield there row's color is change but when is click on another buttonfield the previous row color change to normal color. I want all the row color to change when I click on the buttonfield.I want [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k52te.png) but I get [outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y58bJ.png) when clicking on next buttonfield

```
  front-end code
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"  OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"    >
        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="suser" HeaderText="GR no" SortExpression="suser" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="classname" HeaderText="Class Name" SortExpression="classname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="rollno" HeaderText="Roll No" SortExpression="rollno" />
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="Attendance" Text="Present" CommandName="attendance"  />
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="apsent" HeaderText="Attendance" Text="Apsent" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

   back-end code
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "attendance")
    {                   
        int crow = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        GridView1.Rows[crow].Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GreenYellow;
    }
```

}

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhHLf.png)
 now if I click on  rollno(04) buttonfield then there color changes to green.
like that, if I click on every buttonfield then there respective rollno's color is change

Comment: Not clear, can you post a sample image how you are expecting the output to be

Answer (score 0):

You can the following code

```
Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("green");
```